# Check for only numerical input in batch file

Tags: windows, cmd.exe

In the Windows NT-based command line (mostly for XP or higher), is there a way to verify if a switch being provided is a number only? Depending on the number, I want it to loop through the code *x* number of times

Comment: Personally, I prefer the method in this answer for: [Make sure user entered an integer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/685214/108350).  Use the command processor to do _all_ that work.  You can simplify it to 2 x lines as a minimal solution: 1. `set /a  NO_LINES=%~1`; 2. `if  %NO_LINES% NEQ %~1  goto ABORT`.  When the two are equal - The variable or parameter _is-numeric_.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Edited to fix the regex as per [debham's comment](https://superuser.com/questions/404338/check-for-only-numerical-input-in-batch-file/404359?noredirect=1#comment767687_404359). Turns out that adding a space before the pipe after echo adds a space to the piped string, which was what broke the start/end of line matching previously. The regex could be further improved by discarding whitespace at the beginning and end.

---

There's the `findstr` command. It can search files with regular expressions, much like `grep` in Linux. It can also search piped input.

```
@echo off

set param=%1

echo %param%| findstr /r "^[1-9][0-9]*$">nul

if %errorlevel% equ 0 (
    echo Valid number
)
```

#### Explanation

The parameter used is set into the `param` variable. However, there is nothing stopping you using the parameter directly (`%1` for the first paramater).

`findstr` is used to search the piped input with the `/r` flag for regex.

The pattern:

- `^` means beginning of line.
- `[0-9]` means a digit. The `*` means the previous repeated zero or more times. So `[0-9][0-9]*` means one digit, plus zero or more digits. In other words, at least one digit. The `+` one or more times does not seem to be supported by `findstr`. Note that `[1-9]` is used for the first digit to disallow leading zeroes - see the comments.
- `$` means end of line.

---

Now, a for loop in batch for *x* number of times... if *x* is not a valid number, the loop actually does not run at all - it just gets skipped for the next line. So there is no need to check if the input is a valid number!

```
@echo off

set param=%1

for /l %%a in (1,1,%param%) do (
    echo %%a
)
```

The loop is done using `for /l`, where `(x,y,z)` means start at `x`, increment by `y` until `z` is reached. And it sets `%%a` to the current number/iteration.

**Note: this actually fails if there is a leading zero, causing the command processor to treat it as an octal number. See [dbenham's answer](https://superuser.com/a/618410/117590) for a better solution.**

Comment: Excellent explanation! And easy to use

Comment: As written, this solution will fail with a parameter like `"this 1 fails"` The FINDSTR should do an exact match. It should not do a word match.

Comment: @dbenham Thanks. I tried beginning/end of line matching before, but that failed due to echo passing an extra space. Fixed now.

Comment: @CanadianLuke You may wish to take a look at the edit.

Comment: A value of `09` or `010` could cause problems because of octal notation. See [my answer](http://superuser.com/a/618410/109090) for regex that disallows octal notation.

Comment: @dbenham Huh. Never knew batch even recognised it (in hindsight - it's probably using some standard library function for the conversion - I believe C's one does that). I'll just point people at your answer, though.

Comment: I suspect CMD.EXE has its own number parser, though I haven't any evidence to support that - it's just a gut feeling. I've written up rules as to how CMD.EXE parses numbers in various contexts, all based on empirical evidence: http://www.dostips.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=3758

Answer (score 8):

The following works very well for me. `SET /a param=%1+0` always returns `0` if `%1` is empty or not numeric. Otherwise, it provides the given number.

```
SET /a param=%1+0
IF NOT %param%==0 ECHO Valid number
```

Comment: This will fail if parameter = 0. Also will treat a parameter like "1+1" as a number, which might cause problems, depending on requirements.

Answer (score 8):

This will detect if the first parameter is a valid natural number (non-negative integer).

```
@echo off
echo %1|findstr /xr "[1-9][0-9]* 0" >nul && (
  echo %1 is a valid number
) || (
  echo %1 is NOT a valid number
)
```

If you want to allow quotes around the number, then

```
@echo off
echo "%~1"|findstr /xr /c:\"[1-9][0-9]*\" /c:\"0\" >nul && (
  echo %~1 is a valid number
) || (
  echo %~1 is NOT a valid number
)
```

Note - leading zeros are disallowed because batch treats them as octal, so a value like `09` is invalid, and `010` has a value of 8.

Answer (score 3):

Inspired by [Bob's](https://superuser.com/users/117590/bob) excellent answer with the following additions

- Fix the errorlevel logic
- Implement a DoWork loop/sub that iterates through the number and does
  some arithmetic

---

```
:::::::::::::::
::CountTo.bat
:::::::::::::::
@echo off

::This is the number to test
if "%1"=="" goto :Usage

set param=%1
set matchPattern="^[1-9][0-9]*$"

::test if param matches matchPattern, quietly
:: (redirect stdout to nul, and stderr to stdout)

echo %param%|findstr /r %matchPattern%>nul 2>&1

:: check for errorlevel 1 or higher.  errorlevel 0 is handled as
:: an unchecked fall-through
if errorlevel 1 goto :MyHandleErrorCode

::Success (errorlevel ! >= 1) so proceed.
echo %param% is a valid number
echo  (matches findstr /r %param% %matchPattern%)
echo  findstr returned errorlevel 0

::any other code that the batch file needs to do goes here
echo.
echo Iterating from 1 to %param%
echo.
for /l %%i in (1,1,%param%) do call :DoWork %%i

::anything else,
:: .
:: .

::cleanup
:: .
:: .

::exit the batch file here, skipping embedded subroutines
goto :eof

:::::::::::::::::::::::::
:: Main work subroutine
:::::::::::::::::::::::::
:DoWork
set /a offset = %1 - 1
set /a square = %1 * %1
echo item %1
echo   offset: %offset%
echo   square: %square%
echo.
goto :eof

:::::::::::::::::::::::
:: Error handler code
:::::::::::::::::::::::
:MyHandleErrorCode
echo.
echo CountTo %param%
echo   %param% is not a valid number
echo   (does not match findstr /r %param% %matchPattern%)
echo   findstr returned errorlevel ^>= 1
:: error code doesn't have a goto :eof, we want to drop through to :Usage

::::::::
:Usage
::::::::
echo.
echo Usage:
echo.   CountTo ^<someNumber^>
```

The problem with the following is that it always returns 'Valid number' because 'if errorlevel 0' is always true due to the fact that it is a '>= 0' compare, not a '== 0' compare.

```
@echo off

set param=%1

echo %param%| findstr /r "^[1-9][0-9]*$">nul

if errorlevel 0 (
    echo Valid number
)
```

my $.02

Comment: Whoops... fixed the errorlevel on mine too. Direct numerical comparison rather than the automatic fall-through.

Answer (score 2):

You can validate any variable if its number:

```
SET "var="&for /f "delims=0123456789" %i in ("%a") do set var=%i
if defined var (echo."NIC">nul) else (echo."number")
```

Answer (score 0):

```
set xx=33
echo %xx%
SET /a %xx%+0 2>nul >nul && echo all Digits


set xx=3x3
echo %xx%
SET /a %xx%+0 2>nul >nul || echo No Digits
```

Comment: Can you add some explanation too, please?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know why but on my system the `findstr` command didn't work. The errorlevel wasn't being changed on match or no match.

I did come up with another method though

```
:: Look for all digits. Parse the string and use all the digits as
:: delimiters. If the entire string is a digit then we will get an empty
:: parse value.
SET ALL_DIGITS=0
FOR /F "tokens=* delims=0123456789" %%a IN ("%VALUE%") DO (
    IF "[%%a]" EQU "[]" SET ALL_DIGITS=1
)

IF %ALL_DIGITS% EQU 0 (
    ECHO ERROR: %VALUE% is not all numbers
)
```

Answer (score 0):

One approach:

```
set test_var=001
( 
  (if errorlevel %test_var% break ) 2>nul
)&&(
  echo %test_var% is numeric
)||(
  echo %test_var% is NOT numeric
)

set test_var=001X
( 
  (if errorlevel %test_var% break ) 2>nul
)&&(
  echo %test_var% is numeric
)||(
  echo %test_var% is NOT numeric
)
```

Another:

```
@echo off 

:isInterer  input [returnVar] 
setlocal enableDelayedexpansion 
set "input=%~1" 

if "!input:~0,1!" equ "-" (
    set "input=!input:~1!"
) else (
    if "!input:~0,1!" equ "+" set "input=!input:~1!"
)

for %%# in (1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 0) do ( 
        if not "!input!" == "" ( 
                set "input=!input:%%#=!" 
    )         
) 

if "!input!" equ "" ( 
        set result=true 
) else ( 
        set result=false 
) 

endlocal & if "%~2" neq "" (set %~2=%result%) else echo %result%
```

Answer (score -1):

```
:main 
set /p input=text
if %input% equ 0 goto valid
set /a inputval="%input%"*1
if %inputval% equ 0 goto invalid
goto valid

:invalid
echo Input is not an integer.

:valid
echo Input is an integer.
```

Here is a game that uses this function.

```
@echo off
:main
set /a guessmin=1
set /a guessmax=100
set /a guessrand=%random% %%100 +1
echo.
:check
if %guessmin% equ %guessmax% goto fail
set /p input=- Pick a number %guessmin% - %guessmax%: 
set /a inputval="%input%"*1
if %inputval% equ 0 goto invalid
if %inputval% gtr %guessmax% goto invalid
if %inputval% lss %guessmin% goto invalid
if %inputval% gtr %guessrand% goto high
if %inputval% lss %guessrand% goto low
if %inputval% equ %guessrand% goto mid
:invalid
echo   Please enter a valid number.
echo.
goto check
:high
echo   Your guess was too high.
echo.
set /a guessmax=%inputval%-1
goto check
:low
echo   Your guess was too low.
echo.
set /a guessmin=%inputval%+1
goto check
:mid
echo   Your guess was correct. The game will now reset.
set /p input=- Press enter to play again.
cls
goto main
:fail
echo   You actually managed to lose because there is only
echo   one number remaining. That number is %guessrand%.
set /p input=- Press enter to lose again.
cls
goto main
```